# Get all the caracters before the second occurrence of a character in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to extract the  string located before the second occurrence of '-'

Example:
I have this string: **xx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx**
and I try to have only: **xx-xxxx**

But we can also have this string : **xxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx** and then I need that : **xxx-xxx**

I tried to make it with substring-before/after  but I did not manage to have the desired result. then I wanted to know if this was possible to do that in xslt 1.0?

Sample of code I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="/RESULT">
   <RESULT>
      <xsl:if test="contains(Number,'-')">                 
           <ref>                                                                                                    
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(Number,'-')'')"/>                                                                                  
          </ref>
      </xsl:if>
    </RESULT>
</xsl:template>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show the code you have currently tried please? Thank you!

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I use Saxon9 with xsl version1.0

Comment: Saxon 9 is an XSLT 2.0 (resp. 3.0) processor; you can use regex and/or tokenize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the substring before the first `-` do...

```
substring-before(Number, '-')
```

To get the substring before the second `-`, but after the first `-` do...

```
substring-before(substring-after(Number, '-'), '-')
```

You can then concatenate these to get the value you want

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(Number, '-'), '-', substring-before(substring-after(Number, '-'), '-'))" />
```

If you could use XSLT 2.0 though, you could it like so...

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(Number, '-')[position() &lt;= 2]" separator="-" />
```